# Android: ListView with Checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I've searched high and low for this issue but am not able to find something concrete.

Basically, I have a list of friends in a ListView and I am trying to create a group by choosing specific friends. To do this I have created an Activity with a SearchView and a ListView. Searching will filter and display friends that I want to add. To do so, I want to use a checkbox. All the "checked" friends will then be passed to another activity where the group creation can be complete.

The activity's layout has a `ListView`.
I have written my own adapter and this adapter inflates the row layout for the ListView. The layout of the adapter has a `CheckBox` that I have explicitly added.

So activity layout has: ListView
Row layout has: TextView and Checkbox

But am having issues with:
1. Trying to keep the checkbox checked when scrolling/searching the listview as the view refreshes and the checkbox is recreated as unchecked - I've solved this for the time being by maintaining a list of the checkboxes clicked. I am doing this in the `getView()` method of the adapter.
2. Trying to determine which row of the ListView the checkbox belongs to. I'd need this to then create my group of friends.
3. Allowing to edit the list of chosen friends - to add/remove friends before creating the group.

Here is a diagrammatic representation:
[image]

**EDIT**

Adding in another diagram to show how it works.

So from the first activity, I go to the second one to search and add friends. Once I've chosen my friends, I send the list back to my first activity when I click on 'OK' button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out.

As mentioned, I was not sure how to pass the "control" back to the activity when the checkbox is checked. This was an issue because the checkbox was part of the layout inflated by the adapter.

Within the adapter, I set this up to pass the "control" back to the activity to handle the check on the checkbox:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((SearchFriendActivity) context);
```

And within the SearchFriendActivity, the check on the check box can be handle by:

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Inside onCheckedChanged");

        //The below code line will get the position of the row item    
        int pos = friendlistview.getPositionForView(buttonView);

        if(pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION)
        {
            //Logic Here
        }
    }
```

Remember to `implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` in the activity.

A neat little tutorial on this 
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sk9fRXu53Qs)

Answer (score 0):

There is `AlertDialog` with method `setMultiChoiceItems()` You can make dialog with checkbox list. Could it help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it work or not because i'm not on my dev pc right now i can't post you the code. But try this:

1 Implement checkbox event listener (I'm not sure maybe onCheckChanged()) and store the checkbox value or index in list (better use index)

2 if u had store index, u can tell which checkbox belong to which row. if not maybe u should setTag() to row or TextView of row so u can compare it before intent to next activity.

3 you don't tell us what view that group use. It hard to answer but i think value u got from getIntent() maybe a list so u can display it with some view with remove button. So just remove value from list before create group.
For add more friends maybe u should intent the list intent back to first activity and check the checkbox where it checked and allow user to check/uncheck it again. After that just intent it to that group activity again.

Comment: The checkbox is part of the row layout and so is inflated by the adapter. The listview is part of the activity's layout and is infalted by the activity.

Comment: what are you telling me? I try to answer your question not ask you the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy task, follow the steps:

1. make a layout xml file and define how a single check box will look
2. create a list view.
3. populate the listview as listview is populated for simple textview.

If you don't have enough idea about populating list view then try this link

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

let me know if you face any problem with this.

happy coding!!

Comment: The problem I am having is to detect the rows being chosen in the listview and sending it back to an activity. As the checkbox is part of the row layout, I am not sure how I can "access" it in my activity class rather than the adapter class.

Comment: CheckBox checkBox= ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.cb);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});

Comment: Take a collection and add an item to the collection when checkbox is checked and remove the item from the collection when checkbox is unchecked.